# Angular 4 - Page Unresponsive After Deploying to IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, angular, google-chrome, iis, deployment

While the app works perfectly in the **DEBUG** mode, most of the time, it hangs or shows `Unresponsive Page` error in chrome.

I haven't test it in other browsers because what I've written won't work in other browsers at all.

Unfortunately have no idea how I can monitor requests in IIS.

I should say that both `Server App` and `Angular 4 App` are hosted on the local IIS v10 with individual `application pools`.

I already used `--enable-logging --v=1 --vmodule=metrics=2` command when starting `google-chrome`, but I guess nothing important are being saved in `chrome_debug.log` file or at least I can't read it.

Comment: did you build using ng build --prod ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaMankala Actually not with `--prod` option, Is it necessary to use?

Comment: I faced same issue when I deplyed in express server, --prod solved it. you can give it a try

Comment: @ChaitanyaMankala Unfortunately it didn't make any change. thanks